# Any way to restart LogMeIn Hamachi on a remote machine?

Tags: vpn, macos

LogMeIn Hamachi is crashing on a remote Mac, and I need to restart it without restarting the machine (because then I would lose access entirely.)

I tried un/re-loading the global agent/daemons:

- `/Library/Application Support/LogMeIn Hamachi/bin/hamachid`
- `/Applications/LogMeIn Hamachi/LogMeIn Hamachi Menubar.app/Contents/MacOS/LogMeIn Hamachi Menubar`

but it still fails. App keeps launching and crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I simply uninstalled and re-installed.